# Show that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X>t\}}|\mathcal{G})$ is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a non-negative integral random vairable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and let $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. I want to show that $$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>t|\mathcal{G})dt.$$

I have done most part, but I had a hard to time to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>t|\mathcal{G})dt$$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

---

To show the measurability, define $h(t,\omega):=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X>t\}}|\mathcal{G})(\omega)$, and my idea is to show that $h(t,\omega)$ is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. Then, the desired measurability follows from Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

However, what I know is that $h(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable for each $t$. Also, what I can say more is that since $X$ is a random variable, a regular conditional distribution always exists for $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$, and thus we can take $\mathbb{P}(X>t|\mathcal{G})$ to be a version of this regular conditional probability distribution.

But then what should I do? My idea is to show that the following collection $$\mathcal{E}:=\{(a,\infty):h^{-1}((a,\infty))\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{G}\}$$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. If we can show this, then since $\mathcal{E}$ contains a generating set of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. It is not hard to show that it is closed under countable union and complement since the preimage of the function preserves these. However, how to show that $\mathcal{E}$ is not empty and contains the whole real line?

Am I heading to a correct direction?

---

**Edit1: Attempt but not sure**

Since $X$ is a random variable, a regular conditional distribution always exists for $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$, and thus we can take $\mathbb{P}(X>t|\mathcal{G})$ to be a version of this regular conditional probability distribution. In particular, $F(t,\omega):=1-h(t,\omega)$ is then a regular distribution function so that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $F(t,\omega)$ is a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $$h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\in \{0\}\times A,\ \text{for any}\ A\in\mathcal{G}.$$ Since $\{0\}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Am I correct?

Comment: If you look at the proof of Fubini's theorem (or construction of the product measure) from Royden or some other standard texts like Bogachev for eg, you'll see that for measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{G},\nu)$ , you have that for a function $f:X\times Y\to\Bbb{R}$, the function $g(y)=\int_{X}f(x,y)\,d\mu(x)$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable. Here, your $f(t,\omega)$ is $E(\mathbf{1}_{\{X>t\}}|\mathcal{G})(\omega)$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I believe that the function $f:X\times Y\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is required to be $(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable in the first place, which is what I am trying to show here.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I made a classic mistake to think that if projections are measurable then the function is measurable.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron No problem! I was checking your last comment and yeah, projections being measurable are necessary. Thx for helping and discussing!

Comment: Your $h(t, \omega)$ is not well defined, since each $h(t, \cdot) = P(X > t \mid G)$ is only defined almost surely on a set that depends on $t$ and there are uncountably many $t$. But if you work with a regular conditional probability kernel, the proof for your problem is easy.

Comment: @Mason Yes. I am working with the regular conditional distribution with the kernel satisfying $\mu(\omega, A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A|\mathcal{G})(\omega)$ almost surely and for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. So that $h(\omega, t)=\mu(\omega, (t,\infty)$. However, I still don't know why $h(\omega, t)$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Mason All I know is that $\omega\mapsto \mu(\omega, A)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\kappa : \Omega \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0, 1]$ be a regular conditional probability kernel for $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$. We have $P(X > t \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = \kappa(\omega, \{X > t\}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{(t, \infty)}(x)\kappa(\omega,dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t,x)\kappa(\omega,dx)$, where $f(t, x) = 1_{(t, \infty)}(x)$. Note that $f$ is measurable. Now let
$$\mathcal{C} = \{g : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty) \mid (t, \omega) \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t, x)\kappa(\omega, dx)\text{ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{G}$-measurable }\}.$$
If $g(t, x) = 1_A(t)1_B(x)$ with $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t, x)\kappa(\omega, dx) = 1_A(t)\kappa(\omega, B)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{G}$-measurable. Then since the collection of sets whose indicator functions are in $\mathcal{C}$ can be shown to be a $\lambda$-system, by the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, $\mathcal{C}$ contains all indicators of measurable sets. Then by linearity of integration and monotone convergence, $\mathcal{C}$ contains all $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{G}$-measurable functions.

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, does $\mathbf{1}_{B}(x)$ make sense for $B\in\mathcal{G}$? And why is $\mathbf{1}_{A}(t)\kappa(\omega, B)$ measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra? Could also elaborate on why the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem can finish the proof?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical It was a typo, obviously $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. $t \mapsto 1_A(t)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable by definition and $\omega \mapsto \kappa(\omega, B)$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable by definition. Since projections are product measurable by definition and products of measurable functions are measurable, $(t, \omega) \mapsto 1_A(t)\kappa(\omega, B)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{G}$ measurable.

Comment: I fixed my answer to detail how the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem was used.

Comment: Clever way to use the measurability of projections. Thx!